# Wrong ordering in generated table in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This (should) be a rather simple thing to do, however I am struggling.

I want a table to be generated like this:

```
id 
organizationNumber 
name
```

However, when I look in the database, I see that the ordering is wrong. Does anybody know how I can force hibernate/jpa to generate the table with correct ordering?

```
desc Organization;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| name               | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| organizationNumber | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                | 
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is how my entity bean looks like:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "allOrganizations", query = "SELECT org FROM Organization org order by name")
public class Organization {

    private Long id;
    private String organizationNumber;
    private String name;

    public Organization() {
    }

    public Organization(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    public String getOrganizationNumber() {
        return organizationNumber;
    }
       public void setOrganizationNumber(String organizationNumber) {
        this.organizationNumber = organizationNumber;
    }


    @NotEmpty
    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + " " + this.organizationNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Hibernate generates columns in **alphabetical** order. According to [this post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=974532) the reason is given as:

> It is sorted to ensurce deterministic
> ordering across clusters.
>
> We can't rely on the vm to return the
> methods in the same order every time
> so we had to do something.

Apparently it used to be in the order of occurrence but this changed between 3.2.0 GA and 3.2.1 GA.

I also found [Schema auto generation creates columns in alphabetical order for compound primary keys](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/HIBERNATE-112) and this seems to be like your problem. This ticket is about the order changing in primary keys and that negatively impacts index performance.

There is no fix for this other than a workaround of naming the columns in such a way that they come out in the correct order (no, I'm not kidding).

Comment: Your answer about why it is this way are correct, since there is no real ordering when it comes to annotations. 

Another solution is not use schema auto generation.

Comment: Couldn't you use reflection, iterate over the Fields and build a column list that way?

Comment: LOL. I can't understand how difficult it can be to have a value in the @Column(order=1) so that it takes an order element and then ensures correct ordering. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Shervin I think **it is difficult**. The definition of `@Column` is specified in JPA specification, so it's not up to Hibernate to change it. They need to push for a new feature to be included in the next iteration of JPA through the working group / community -- and this will be subject to agreement by other vendors.

Comment: Still nothing in 2019 ?

Comment: Hibernate 5.x :

1) In annotation approach:
The column order would be in alphabet order of Column names specify in Persistence class

2) In XML approach:
The column order would be in the same order, as specified in hibernate.hbm.xml

Comment: Ordering columns is useful for easier reading but should not ever be relied upon in SQL statements.  The same mistake occurs when dev write selects expecting data to be returning in a consistent order without specifying ordering in the SQL: the results ordering is, by definition, UNDEFINED.  Let's remember what we right affects the end users and they need consistency.

Comment: Still nothing in 2020? It's hibernate 5.4.25 now. Fine! I will use DBeaver.

Comment: Still nothing in 2022? Please

Comment: Still nothing in 2023! :/

Comment: actually, see the solution in the answer by @Changemyminds .. it's amazing and i can't fathom why the hibernate folks can't adopt it!

Answer (score 11):

I have the same problem. Finally, I found the solution.

Find your External Libraries about hibernate core and find the `org.hibernate.cfg.PropertyContainer` class and copy the content.

[image]

In your root folder create the `org.hibernate.cfg` package and `PropertyContainer` class.
[image]

Paste the `org.hibernate.cfg.PropertyContainer` content and replace all `TreeMap` to `LinkedHashMap` in your create `PropertyContainer` class.

```
/*
 * Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
 *
 * License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
 * See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.
 */

// $Id$

package org.hibernate.cfg;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.hibernate.AnnotationException;
import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ManyToAny;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Target;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.XClass;
import org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.XProperty;
import org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.Origin;
import org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.SourceType;
import org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.HCANNHelper;
import org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.StringHelper;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

/**
 * A helper class to keep the {@code XProperty}s of a class ordered by access type.
 *
 * @author Hardy Ferentschik
 */
class PropertyContainer {
//
//    static {
//        System.setProperty("jboss.i18n.generate-proxies", "true");
//    }

    private static final CoreMessageLogger LOG = Logger.getMessageLogger(CoreMessageLogger.class, PropertyContainer.class.getName());

    /**
     * The class for which this container is created.
     */
    private final XClass xClass;
    private final XClass entityAtStake;

    /**
     * Holds the AccessType indicated for use at the class/container-level for cases where persistent attribute
     * did not specify.
     */
    private final AccessType classLevelAccessType;

    private final TreeMap<String, XProperty> persistentAttributeMap;

    PropertyContainer(XClass clazz, XClass entityAtStake, AccessType defaultClassLevelAccessType) {
        this.xClass = clazz;
        this.entityAtStake = entityAtStake;

        if ( defaultClassLevelAccessType == AccessType.DEFAULT ) {
            // this is effectively what the old code did when AccessType.DEFAULT was passed in
            // to getProperties(AccessType) from AnnotationBinder and InheritanceState
            defaultClassLevelAccessType = AccessType.PROPERTY;
        }

        AccessType localClassLevelAccessType = determineLocalClassDefinedAccessStrategy();
        assert localClassLevelAccessType != null;

        this.classLevelAccessType = localClassLevelAccessType != AccessType.DEFAULT
                ? localClassLevelAccessType
                : defaultClassLevelAccessType;
        assert classLevelAccessType == AccessType.FIELD || classLevelAccessType == AccessType.PROPERTY;

        this.persistentAttributeMap = new TreeMap<String, XProperty>();

        final List<XProperty> fields = xClass.getDeclaredProperties( AccessType.FIELD.getType() );
        final List<XProperty> getters = xClass.getDeclaredProperties( AccessType.PROPERTY.getType() );

        preFilter( fields, getters );

        final Map<String,XProperty> persistentAttributesFromGetters = new HashMap<String, XProperty>();

        collectPersistentAttributesUsingLocalAccessType(
                persistentAttributeMap,
                persistentAttributesFromGetters,
                fields,
                getters
        );
        collectPersistentAttributesUsingClassLevelAccessType(
                persistentAttributeMap,
                persistentAttributesFromGetters,
                fields,
                getters
        );
    }

    private void preFilter(List<XProperty> fields, List<XProperty> getters) {
        Iterator<XProperty> propertyIterator = fields.iterator();
        while ( propertyIterator.hasNext() ) {
            final XProperty property = propertyIterator.next();
            if ( mustBeSkipped( property ) ) {
                propertyIterator.remove();
            }
        }

        propertyIterator = getters.iterator();
        while ( propertyIterator.hasNext() ) {
            final XProperty property = propertyIterator.next();
            if ( mustBeSkipped( property ) ) {
                propertyIterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private void collectPersistentAttributesUsingLocalAccessType(
            TreeMap<String, XProperty> persistentAttributeMap,
            Map<String,XProperty> persistentAttributesFromGetters,
            List<XProperty> fields,
            List<XProperty> getters) {

        // Check fields...
        Iterator<XProperty> propertyIterator = fields.iterator();
        while ( propertyIterator.hasNext() ) {
            final XProperty xProperty = propertyIterator.next();
            final Access localAccessAnnotation = xProperty.getAnnotation( Access.class );
            if ( localAccessAnnotation == null
                    || localAccessAnnotation.value() != javax.persistence.AccessType.FIELD ) {
                continue;
            }

            propertyIterator.remove();
            persistentAttributeMap.put( xProperty.getName(), xProperty );
        }

        // Check getters...
        propertyIterator = getters.iterator();
        while ( propertyIterator.hasNext() ) {
            final XProperty xProperty = propertyIterator.next();
            final Access localAccessAnnotation = xProperty.getAnnotation( Access.class );
            if ( localAccessAnnotation == null
                    || localAccessAnnotation.value() != javax.persistence.AccessType.PROPERTY ) {
                continue;
            }

            propertyIterator.remove();

            final String name = xProperty.getName();

            // HHH-10242 detect registration of the same property getter twice - eg boolean isId() + UUID getId()
            final XProperty previous = persistentAttributesFromGetters.get( name );
            if ( previous != null ) {
                throw new org.hibernate.boot.MappingException(
                        LOG.ambiguousPropertyMethods(
                                xClass.getName(),
                                HCANNHelper.annotatedElementSignature( previous ),
                                HCANNHelper.annotatedElementSignature( xProperty )
                        ),
                        new Origin( SourceType.ANNOTATION, xClass.getName() )
                );
            }

            persistentAttributeMap.put( name, xProperty );
            persistentAttributesFromGetters.put( name, xProperty );
        }
    }

    private void collectPersistentAttributesUsingClassLevelAccessType(
            TreeMap<String, XProperty> persistentAttributeMap,
            Map<String,XProperty> persistentAttributesFromGetters,
            List<XProperty> fields,
            List<XProperty> getters) {
        if ( classLevelAccessType == AccessType.FIELD ) {
            for ( XProperty field : fields ) {
                if ( persistentAttributeMap.containsKey( field.getName() ) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                persistentAttributeMap.put( field.getName(), field );
            }
        }
        else {
            for ( XProperty getter : getters ) {
                final String name = getter.getName();

                // HHH-10242 detect registration of the same property getter twice - eg boolean isId() + UUID getId()
                final XProperty previous = persistentAttributesFromGetters.get( name );
                if ( previous != null ) {
                    throw new org.hibernate.boot.MappingException(
                            LOG.ambiguousPropertyMethods(
                                    xClass.getName(),
                                    HCANNHelper.annotatedElementSignature( previous ),
                                    HCANNHelper.annotatedElementSignature( getter )
                            ),
                            new Origin( SourceType.ANNOTATION, xClass.getName() )
                    );
                }

                if ( persistentAttributeMap.containsKey( name ) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                persistentAttributeMap.put( getter.getName(), getter );
                persistentAttributesFromGetters.put( name, getter );
            }
        }
    }

    public XClass getEntityAtStake() {
        return entityAtStake;
    }

    public XClass getDeclaringClass() {
        return xClass;
    }

    public AccessType getClassLevelAccessType() {
        return classLevelAccessType;
    }

    public Collection<XProperty> getProperties() {
        assertTypesAreResolvable();
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection( persistentAttributeMap.values() );
    }

    private void assertTypesAreResolvable() {
        for ( XProperty xProperty : persistentAttributeMap.values() ) {
            if ( !xProperty.isTypeResolved() && !discoverTypeWithoutReflection( xProperty ) ) {
                String msg = "Property " + StringHelper.qualify( xClass.getName(), xProperty.getName() ) +
                        " has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue" +
                        " or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type";
                throw new AnnotationException( msg );
            }
        }
    }
//
//  private void considerExplicitFieldAndPropertyAccess() {
//      for ( XProperty property : fieldAccessMap.values() ) {
//          Access access = property.getAnnotation( Access.class );
//          if ( access == null ) {
//              continue;
//          }
//
//          // see "2.3.2 Explicit Access Type" of JPA 2 spec
//          // the access type for this property is explicitly set to AccessType.FIELD, hence we have to
//          // use field access for this property even if the default access type for the class is AccessType.PROPERTY
//          AccessType accessType = AccessType.getAccessStrategy( access.value() );
//            if (accessType == AccessType.FIELD) {
//              propertyAccessMap.put(property.getName(), property);
//          }
//            else {
//              LOG.debug( "Placing @Access(AccessType.FIELD) on a field does not have any effect." );
//          }
//      }
//
//      for ( XProperty property : propertyAccessMap.values() ) {
//          Access access = property.getAnnotation( Access.class );
//          if ( access == null ) {
//              continue;
//          }
//
//          AccessType accessType = AccessType.getAccessStrategy( access.value() );
//
//          // see "2.3.2 Explicit Access Type" of JPA 2 spec
//          // the access type for this property is explicitly set to AccessType.PROPERTY, hence we have to
//          // return use method access even if the default class access type is AccessType.FIELD
//            if (accessType == AccessType.PROPERTY) {
//              fieldAccessMap.put(property.getName(), property);
//          }
//            else {
//              LOG.debug( "Placing @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) on a field does not have any effect." );
//          }
//      }
//  }

//  /**
//   * Retrieves all properties from the {@code xClass} with the specified access type. This method does not take
//   * any jpa access rules/annotations into account yet.
//   *
//   * @param access The access type - {@code AccessType.FIELD}  or {@code AccessType.Property}
//   *
//   * @return A maps of the properties with the given access type keyed against their property name
//   */
//  private TreeMap<String, XProperty> initProperties(AccessType access) {
//      if ( !( AccessType.PROPERTY.equals( access ) || AccessType.FIELD.equals( access ) ) ) {
//          throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Access type has to be AccessType.FIELD or AccessType.Property" );
//      }
//
//      //order so that property are used in the same order when binding native query
//      TreeMap<String, XProperty> propertiesMap = new TreeMap<String, XProperty>();
//      List<XProperty> properties = xClass.getDeclaredProperties( access.getType() );
//      for ( XProperty property : properties ) {
//          if ( mustBeSkipped( property ) ) {
//              continue;
//          }
//          // HHH-10242 detect registration of the same property twice eg boolean isId() + UUID getId()
//          XProperty oldProperty = propertiesMap.get( property.getName() );
//          if ( oldProperty != null ) {
//              throw new org.hibernate.boot.MappingException(
//                      LOG.ambiguousPropertyMethods(
//                              xClass.getName(),
//                              HCANNHelper.annotatedElementSignature( oldProperty ),
//                              HCANNHelper.annotatedElementSignature( property )
//                      ),
//                      new Origin( SourceType.ANNOTATION, xClass.getName() )
//              );
//          }
//
//          propertiesMap.put( property.getName(), property );
//      }
//      return propertiesMap;
//  }

    private AccessType determineLocalClassDefinedAccessStrategy() {
        AccessType classDefinedAccessType;

        AccessType hibernateDefinedAccessType = AccessType.DEFAULT;
        AccessType jpaDefinedAccessType = AccessType.DEFAULT;

        org.hibernate.annotations.AccessType accessType = xClass.getAnnotation( org.hibernate.annotations.AccessType.class );
        if ( accessType != null ) {
            hibernateDefinedAccessType = AccessType.getAccessStrategy( accessType.value() );
        }

        Access access = xClass.getAnnotation( Access.class );
        if ( access != null ) {
            jpaDefinedAccessType = AccessType.getAccessStrategy( access.value() );
        }

        if ( hibernateDefinedAccessType != AccessType.DEFAULT
                && jpaDefinedAccessType != AccessType.DEFAULT
                && hibernateDefinedAccessType != jpaDefinedAccessType ) {
            throw new MappingException(
                    "@AccessType and @Access specified with contradicting values. Use of @Access only is recommended. "
            );
        }

        if ( hibernateDefinedAccessType != AccessType.DEFAULT ) {
            classDefinedAccessType = hibernateDefinedAccessType;
        }
        else {
            classDefinedAccessType = jpaDefinedAccessType;
        }
        return classDefinedAccessType;
    }

    private static boolean discoverTypeWithoutReflection(XProperty p) {
        if ( p.isAnnotationPresent( OneToOne.class ) && !p.getAnnotation( OneToOne.class )
                .targetEntity()
                .equals( void.class ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( p.isAnnotationPresent( OneToMany.class ) && !p.getAnnotation( OneToMany.class )
                .targetEntity()
                .equals( void.class ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( p.isAnnotationPresent( ManyToOne.class ) && !p.getAnnotation( ManyToOne.class )
                .targetEntity()
                .equals( void.class ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( p.isAnnotationPresent( ManyToMany.class ) && !p.getAnnotation( ManyToMany.class )
                .targetEntity()
                .equals( void.class ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( p.isAnnotationPresent( org.hibernate.annotations.Any.class ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( p.isAnnotationPresent( ManyToAny.class ) ) {
            if ( !p.isCollection() && !p.isArray() ) {
                throw new AnnotationException( "@ManyToAny used on a non collection non array property: " + p.getName() );
            }
            return true;
        }
        else if ( p.isAnnotationPresent( Type.class ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( p.isAnnotationPresent( Target.class ) ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean mustBeSkipped(XProperty property) {
        //TODO make those hardcoded tests more portable (through the bytecode provider?)
        return property.isAnnotationPresent( Transient.class )
                || "net.sf.cglib.transform.impl.InterceptFieldCallback".equals( property.getType().getName() )
                || "org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.javassist.FieldHandler".equals( property.getType().getName() );
    }
}
```

Fixed the Organization class.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Organization {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String organizationNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public Organization() {
    }

    public Organization(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOrganizationNumber() {
        return organizationNumber;
    }

    public void setOrganizationNumber(String organizationNumber) {
        this.organizationNumber = organizationNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + " " + this.organizationNumber;
    }
}
```

Start the Spring Boot App. See the result in the console.

```
Hibernate: create table organization (id bigint not null, organization_number varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255) not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
```

In the database see the desc result.

```
mysql> desc organization;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| organization_number | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| name                | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

#### Supplement on Inheritance

If you want use the inherit some parent class like Auditing class. The above answer is not enough.

You can copy `InheritanceState.class` like above approach and create the `InheritanceState.class` into `org.hibernate.cfg package`.

Modify the two line, just fixed the sorting.

```
public class InheritanceState {
    // ...
    private void getMappedSuperclassesTillNextEntityOrdered() {

        //ordered to allow proper messages on properties subclassing
        XClass currentClassInHierarchy = clazz;
        InheritanceState superclassState;
        do {
              // mark this ↓↓↓↓↓
//            classesToProcessForMappedSuperclass.add( 0, currentClassInHierarchy );

            // fixed the sorting, add this ↓↓↓↓↓
            classesToProcessForMappedSuperclass.add( currentClassInHierarchy );
            
            // ...
        }
        // ... 
    }
    
   private void addMappedSuperClassInMetadata(PersistentClass persistentClass) {
        //add @MappedSuperclass in the metadata
        // classes from 0 to n-1 are @MappedSuperclass and should be linked
        org.hibernate.mapping.MappedSuperclass mappedSuperclass = null;
        final InheritanceState superEntityState =
                InheritanceState.getInheritanceStateOfSuperEntity( clazz, inheritanceStatePerClass );
        PersistentClass superEntity =
                superEntityState != null ?
                        buildingContext.getMetadataCollector().getEntityBinding( superEntityState.getClazz().getName() ) :
                        null;
        final int lastMappedSuperclass = classesToProcessForMappedSuperclass.size() - 1;
        
        // mark this ↓↓↓↓↓
//        for ( int index = 0; index < lastMappedSuperclass; index++ ) {

        // fixed the sorting, add this ↓↓↓↓↓
        for ( int index = lastMappedSuperclass; index > 0; index-- ) {
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }   
}
```

The demo class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AuditableEntity {
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by")
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "update_time")
    private ZonedDateTime updatedTime;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "create_time")
    private ZonedDateTime createTime;
}

@Entity
public class OrganizationAudit extends AuditableEntity {
   // same field with Organization.class...
}
```

In console result.

```
create table organization_audit (id bigint not null, organization_number varchar(255) not null, name varchar(255) not null, created_by varchar(255), last_modified_by varchar(255), update_time datetime, create_time datetime, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
```

In database result.

```
mysql> desc organization_audit;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| organization_number | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| name                | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_by          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| last_modified_by    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| update_time         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| create_time         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The sample project is [here](https://github.com/changemyminds/Demo-Spring-JPA-Generate-Table).

Comment: wow, just wow! amazing find!!

Comment: but are we sure this wont conflict with other dependencies like flyway? or when we change the entity, how ton confirm this is 100% safe i wonder!

Answer (score 8):

You can set the order you want whenever you can change the *internal* name of the class members, since the order of the columns is taken from the field name, not from the getter, setter, or column.

Thus, if the class members are private (as desired), you should only list them (for example by prefixing them with "a_", "b_", "c_", ...) without changing either the getters, the setters, or the column names.

For example, the following class definition:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "parent")
UUID parent;

@Id
@Column(name = "type", length = 10)
String type;

@Id
@Column(name = "child")
UUID child;
```

It generates the following table:

```
  Column   |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 child     | uuid                  |           | not null | 
 parent    | uuid                  |           | not null | 
 type      | character varying(10) |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "...whatever..." PRIMARY KEY, btree (child, parent, type)
```

Which is not efficient because normally we will search by parent and type of relationship to obtain the children.

We can change the private names without affecting the rest of the implementation by doing:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "parent")
UUID a_parent;

@Id
@Column(name = "type", length = 10)
String b_type;

@Id
@Column(name = "child")
UUID c_child;

public UUID getParent() { return a_parent; }
public UUID getChild() { return c_child; }
public String getType() { return b_type; }
public void setParent(UUID parent) { a_parent = parent; }
public void setChild(UUID child) { c_child = child; }
public void setType(String type) { b_type = type; }
```

In that it has now been generated:

```
  Column   |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 parent    | uuid                  |           | not null | 
 type      | character varying(10) |           | not null | 
 child     | uuid                  |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "...whatever..." PRIMARY KEY, btree (parent, type, child)
```

Of course it is not best to depend on the internal lexicographical order of the class members but I do not see a better solution.

Comment: I think makes a better, cleaner and simpler solution compared to the other alternates. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it's really ugly workaround :(

Comment: and if you are using lombok, then you have problems here too :D

Answer (score 5):

DataNucleus allows the extension specifying the position for schema generation, FWIW.

Comment: I would suggest : As soon a table created by Hibernate, you may ALTER it  to order the columns as the way you want. I have done so. Tools like Toad will make it very easy through column Up/Down option over UI

Comment: Can you please share, How can I alter my table column up/down using Jpa? @sabarinathanu

Answer (score 5):

**2023 Update**

Hibernate 6.2 intoduced the [ColumnOrderingStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/relational/ColumnOrderingStrategy.html) interface. The default strategy is now the [ColumnOrderingStrategyStandard](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/relational/ColumnOrderingStrategyStandard.html). The docs say:

> Standard implementation that orders columns by size and name following
> roughly this ordering: `order by max(physicalSizeBytes, 4), physicalSizeBytes > 2048, name`

You can read about the reasoning why it was introduced and done this way and not for example through an annotation in this [discussion](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/discussions/3989). There is also a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/534877) on SO on this topic.

You can implement your own strategy by implementing the ColumnOrderingStrategy interface and setting your implementation via the `hibernate.column_ordering_strategy` property or [AvailableSettings.COLUMN_ORDERING_STRATEGY](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/MappingSettings.html#COLUMN_ORDERING_STRATEGY).

You can go back to the old behavior by setting `hibernate.column_ordering_strategy=legacy`

For more details i've written a blog post about it: https://robertniestroj.hashnode.dev/ordering-columns-in-a-table-in-jpahibernate

Answer (score 0):

Just create that Table using **create** statement in your database and use Hibernate to insert a value into Table

Comment: Other languages allow me to generate schema in exact order of fields from code, because why not? Entity should be source of truth. This is ugly workaround :(

Answer (score 0):

Only to resolve the inheritance for the auditable class as an example,
JPA doesn't respect the alpha order, will create first the auditable columns, in this case, for the columns of the auditable class to be created last!

You need to comment `@MappedSuperclass`, then run in sequence with 'create', then uncomment and run with 'update' for the 'ddl-auto' option.