# Write Unicode Letters into a database via JPQL

Tags: database, unicode, jpql, nvarchar

I have a database which has a table which has a column with the datatype nvarchar2. This means it can store unicode data. A good thing is when I insert for example chinese letters manually I can read them via JPQL and print them in my console. The bad thing is when I insert something via JPQL into it, every non latin character is changed to "¿". Does anyone of you know how I can fix that problem?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate? Try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13064070/2387977