# JavaFx application database font representation problem

Tags: mysql, hibernate, javafx, fonts, windows-7

[javafx font issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDfT2.png)[javafx application font issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boyEH.png)

**Problem**
Hi, 
i am studying javaFX, and trying to run aplication which showing data from database MySQL8 + Hibernate.
Data and files are shown, but there some issue with font presentataion.
Could you advice something, how to fix it?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AppTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/allAdsView.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("My First App");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1280, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

it's because the character encoding and default font "System" font is used, 
add this to your css (or any other font you wish to use),

```
* {
-fx-font-family: 'Arial';
}
```

since you said MySQL8 + Hibernate, you should also check the character encoding in the database. check this post,
[Hibernate + MySQL: How to set the encoding utf-8 for database and tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063372/hibernate-mysql-how-to-set-the-encoding-utf-8-for-database-and-tables)

Comment: thanks, but this solution did not help, one of my frirend run this code, and he had proper representation. I think it is problem in windows fonts