# How to align columns in the table using spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an application to create a simple SQL table with the following columns:

> 1. FirstName
> 2. LastName
> 3. Age
> 4. Gender

And the column order should be the same. But I am getting different order than expected. I am using spring boot and JPA. I have the model class with the same order, but some how I'm not getting the expected output. Can anyone please help on this? Thanks in advance!

Expected order should be `(FirstName, LastName, Age, Gender)`. Getting the shuffled order.

Comment: Why do you care about the order for the columns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate: Reversed column order by hbm2ddl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433998/hibernate-reversed-column-order-by-hbm2ddl)