# I want to know about Hibernate annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a question about "annotations" in hibernate.
 I have a BaseEntity class  and another class like state.java who extend

```
 @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "createdBy", "updatedBy" })
    @MappedSuperclass

public abstract class BaseEntity<T> implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private T                   id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CreatedBy", nullable = true)
    private User                createdBy;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "UpdatedBy", nullable = true)
    private User                updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "createdDate", nullable = true, updatable = false)
    private Date                createdDate;

    @Column(name = "UpdatedDate", nullable = true)
    private Date                updatedDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subsite", nullable = true)
    private Subsite             subsite;

    @Column(name = "ip", nullable = true)
    private String              ip;


@Entity
@Table(name="State")
public class State extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    @Column(name = "state", nullable = true)
    private String  state;

    @Column(name = "city", nullable = true)
    private String  city;
```

when program creat my tables in DataBase my table'design build like this:

[image]

How can I create a table so that  the  BaseEntity'fields  place  after state'fields  in  my Table

Comment: Might be a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298322/wrong-ordering-in-generated-table-in-jpa