# How to organize database columns in same order as specified in model on Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I created a model in Spring Boot with these fields:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Column(name = "coinmarketcap_slug")
private String coinmarketcapSlug;

@Column(name = "coinmarketcap_id")
private int coinmarketcapId;

@Column(name = "symbol")
private String symbol;

@Column(name = "twitter_screen_name")
private String twitterScreenName;

@Column(name = "subreddit")
private String subreddit;

@Column(name = "facebook")
private String facebook;

@Column(name = "youtube")
private String youtube;

@Column(name = "linkedin")
private String linkedin;

@Column(name = "instagram")
private String instagram;

@Column(name = "medium")
private String medium;

@Column(name = "github")
private String github;

@Column(name = "stackexchange")
private String stackexchange;

@Column(name = "meetup")
private String meetup;

@Column(name = "gitter")
private String gitter;

@Column(name = "logo")
private String logo;
```

I activated this option to allow Hibernate to sync the database tables with the entity fields:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Here is the result:

[image]

Unfortunately the columns are not organized in the same order that I specified in my model.

I used to work with Doctrine on PHP, and it does it automatically by default.

Is it possible to do that with Hibernate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298322/wrong-ordering-in-generated-table-in-jpa