# Why POJO attribute position changed in database MySql while using OneToMany unidirectional mapping with annotation?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, annotations

I have two POJO Teacher(One) any Student(Many) and mapping is done by 
    annotation. The code is working fine but I have doubt regarding the order of 
    position of attributes in database MySql

```
@Entity @Table(name="teacher") public class Teacher {
@Id @Column(name="tId") private Integer teacherId;
@Column(name="teacherName", length=20) private String teacherName;
@Column(name="sub", length=20) private String subject;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Student.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="tid",referencedColumnName="tId")
private Set student;}

@Entity @Table(name="student") public class Student {
@Id @Column(name="rollNo") private Integer studentRollNo;
@Column(name="stdName", length=20) private String studentName;
@Column(name="address", length=20)private String studentAddress;}
```

I expect console output as

```
Hibernate: insert into teacher (tId, teacherName, sub) values (?, ?, ?)
```

but the actual console output is

```
Hibernate: insert into teacher (sub, teacherName, tId) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not care about column order. It uses alphabetical order for columns.

You can find more details in this post - [Wrong ordering in generated table in jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298322/wrong-ordering-in-generated-table-in-jpa)