# How to order columns in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the below class:

```
@Table(name = "Code_Master")
public class CodeMaster {

    @Column(name = "Grade")
    private String grade;

    @Column(name = "Code")
    private Integer code;

    @Column(name = "Code_Name")
    private String codeName;

    @Column(name = "Company")
    private Integer company;

    @Column(name = "Case")
    private Integer case;
}
```

This generates my table in Database with sorted column names, in the order: 
case 
code 
codeName 
company 
grade

However, I do not want this order. I want the column order that is specified in the class.

I have searched throught, but could not find a way to change the create table query of spring data jpa.

Resources tried: 
[Wrong ordering in generated table in jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298322/wrong-ordering-in-generated-table-in-jpa) 
https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-creating-database-queries-with-the-query-annotation/ 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-generate-db-schema 
https://thorben-janssen.com/create-generate-table-model/

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Data JPA. Just don't let Hibernate generate the database. Do it yourself, using something like Flyway or Liquibase to manage the migrations.

Comment: Actually, I am supposed to be using JPA for table generation

Comment: Then you have to live with this, either control it yourself or start being happy with what JPA generates. Although it is a bad idea to let JPA generate your schema.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? It is being used in my organization, maybe I could put forth your view

Comment: As you want to control the DB creation. You know which indexes, page sizes, constraints to generate. JPA doesn't know (all of that). It is nice for quick demo's or testing not for your production system.

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot!