# Is there a way to maintain an order column using jpa hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to have a table with an "order" column to allow rearranging the order of data. Is this possible using jpa? Maybe something similar to @OrderColumn but on the table itself.

Basically I want to add a new column called "order" that saves the order the records. If a record is added, it would automatically get a "order" value. If a record was deleted, the "order" of the remaining would be automatically updated. Additionally if possible, to rearrange the orders by moving one record to an lower "order" and it would push the others

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong ordering in generated table in jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298322/wrong-ordering-in-generated-table-in-jpa)

Comment: @KumarAshutosh no, I am looking to the ordering of the actual data

Comment: Try using the @OrderBy annotation

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this out of the box, but you can implement this yourself if you want. Just query for the count of objects right before persisting and set the count + 1 as value for that order column. Make sure that the order column is declared as being unique i.e. with a unique constraint.

Note that your requirement is pretty exotic and will likely require some kind of table lock or retry mechanism if you have high concurrency.

IMO you should ask whoever gave you this requirement what the goal is that should be achieved. I bet that you will find out you don't need this after all.