# how to order columns MySQL in the same order in spring boot framework

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

every time when I make tables in MySQL using spring boot jpa I face the same problem that is the @Columns I specified in the @Entity Class will ordered differently on the database
can any one help with that
thank you very much all of you for your efforts

Comment: Share an example of your code please

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not possible because Hibernate generates columns in alphabetical order. You can read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1298327/7871511